# Is it possible to 'explain' a find query without doing two requests? (by reusing the cursor)

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to log queries that impact on performance. To do so, my idea is to get the stats of each query (`collection.find({query}).explain()`) and register them.
The problem being that after I call explain, I can not get the documents requested (`.toArray()`).

Is it possible to reuse the same cursor to get the stats and the documents without making two requests to the mongo database?

Comment: The result of the explain method is a _query plan_ document - it does'nt produce the query result. To get a _query result_ you need to run the query _without_ the explain. Each  is a _different operation_. But, you can the Database Profiler to collect data about slow queries. Note that you need to activate the profiler (as it is disabled by default) and you can review the database performance related info in the resulting logs. Also, activating profiler can affect the perfomance of the database as it has to do more work and collect profiler data (so make sure to turn it off after its usage).

Comment: Thanks @prasad_. The idea is to explore the possibility of a query returning some stats (apart from the documents) without doing to operations instead of one. I know about profiling and logging, and unless some magical usage of the cursor is possible, it should be the way to retrieve the information I'm looking for